# Passing password between linux commands and Python

Tags: linux, python-2.7

**I want to execute some  Linux commands using  superuser privileges in Python.**

Initially i want to input the password from user and then store the password in variable for future use while executing Linux commands using **Superuser privileges**.

**Below its a sample code, what i intended to do:**

```
import os, sys, getpass**

# To input password from user then use this password while execution of Linux commands using superuser privileges.

password = getpass.getpass()
# Before executing below line it'll prompt to enter the password and here i want to use password variable.

os.system("sudo  -s")
# [sudo] password for <username>: # <Password>
```

After successful execution of above command i  want to execute rest of code as superuser privileges.

NOTE: I want to use standard method (i.e stdin, stdout, stderr, pipe etc) for inputing  password while execution of `os.system("sudo -s")` command. I know there are other methods too to deal with this problem.

For Example:

```
import os

password = "my-password"
command = "echo {0} | sudo -s {1}".format(password, "my-command")
os.system(command)
```

Please assist me, how can i do it or correct me if my intention is wrong  for doing so.

Comment: __NOTE: I want to use standard method for inputing password.__ You mean you prefer using standard input?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pexpect:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pexpect
>>> terminal = pexpect.spawn('/bin/sh')
```

Launching the shell

```
>>> terminal.sendline('sudo aptitude help')
19
```

Sending the command

```
>>> terminal.expect('andy:')
0
```

Expecting `[sudo] password for <user>:` or just `<user>:` to appear in the output (terminal will wait for it)

```
>>> import getpass
>>> password = getpass.getpass()
Password:
```

Getting the password

```
>>> terminal.sendline(password)
16
```

Sending the password to the terminal

```
>>> result = ''
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         result += terminal.read_nonblocking(1, 1)
...     except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
...         break
...
```

Getting the result

```
>>> result
'\r\naptitude 0.7.4\r\n\xd0\x98\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5: aptitude [-S \xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8f \xd1\x84\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0] [-u|-i]\r\n       aptitude [\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd1\x8b] <\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5> \xe2\x80\xa6\r\n  \xd0\x94\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f (\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb7\...'
```

(it's Russian)

Pexpect docs [here](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)